# search and enter the first youtube video using python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Hi I am using youtube api in python.
and i want to that the user will write something in the function at it will automatically
will search for what he wanted and it will get into the first video.
I succeed to  do the search:

```
def start_song(self,song_name):
    words = song_name.split()

    url = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

    for word in words:
        url = url + word + "+"

    time.sleep(1)   #Sleeps for a second
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

but the entry I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scrape videos from a YouTube search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362731/how-can-i-scrape-videos-from-a-youtube-search)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your "song_name" is a sentence where you want to separate words by a space character, you can try this :

```
def start_song(self,song_name):
    words = song_name.split()

    url = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

    for word in words:
        url += word + "+"

    time.sleep(1)   #Sleeps for a second
    webbrowser.open_new(url[:-1])  # -1 because we remove the last "+" inserted
```